# How can I use memoization to improve the run time of this algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, memoization

The problem is stated:

> If we can assign either a positive or negative sign to each integer in
> a set of integers, how many ways can we sum the signed integers to
> equal a target value? We must use every integer in the set.
>
> Eg [1, 2, 3, 2], target = 0
>
> Two ways [-1, 2, -3, 2], and [1, -2, 3,
> -2]

My solution is as follows (java)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[] nums = {1, 2, 3, 2};
  int x = helper(0, 0, nums, 0);
  System.out.println(x);
}

private static int helper(int step, int sumSoFar, int[] nums, int target) {
  if (step == nums.length) {
    return sumSoFar == target ? 1 : 0;
  }

  return
    helper(step + 1, sumSoFar + nums[step], nums, target)
        +
        helper(step + 1, sumSoFar - nums[step], nums, target);
}
```

I understand that there are many possible repeated calculations in a brute force solution, but I can't understand if passing in the sumSoFar variable is effectively forming a memoization technique?

If not, how can I use memoization to improve the runtime performance of this algorithm?

Comment: Is the empty set also an answer? I see multiple values changing in your recursion, I'm not sure that memoization can help.

Comment: I added the condition that we have to use every integer in the set, so the empty set is not a valid solution.

Comment: Sorry. I can say that passing `sumSoFar` does not appear to be any form of memoization. Normally, I would expect there to be an additional array or map to store an entire table of memoized values (to **remember** previous results). But as I already mentioned, I don't see a way to take advantage of memoization to solve this particular problem. That does not mean it does not exist. Just that **I** don't know. Also, the empty set (if it were valid) would only apply to `0` (I think).

Answer (score 0):

You can use hash map for solving this problem with memorization (Ex: Guava Table)

```
Table<Integer, Integer, Integer> calculated = HashBasedTable.create();

private static int helper(int step, int sumSoFar, int[] nums, int target) {
   if (step == nums.length) {
      return sumSoFar == target ? 1 : 0;
   }

   if (calculated.contains(step, sumSoFar)) {
       return calculated.get(step, sumSoFar)
   }
   int result = helper(step + 1, sumSoFar + nums[step], nums, target)
        +
        helper(step + 1, sumSoFar - nums[step], nums, target);
   calculated.put(step, sumSoFar, result);
   return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to achieve "memoization" with following algorithm. I have added one more parameter in recursion - `rest` which can be absolute positive or absolute negative sum of the non-seen elements. So it breaks recursion if there is no chance to reach the target.

With this approach, worst case is still O(2^n) - i.e. [0,0,0,0], but in practice it is faster.

Note: assumption is that elements in nums are positive, if not you can make them in O(n).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] nums = {1, 2, 3, 2};
    int totalSumSum = arraySum(nums);

    int x = helper(-1, 0, nums, 0, totalSumSum);
    System.out.println(x);

}


private static int helper(int step, int sumSoFar, int[] nums, int target, int rest) {

    if (step == nums.length-1) {
        return sumSoFar == target ? 1 : 0;
    }

    int nextStep = step+1;
    int nextSumPos = sumSoFar + nums[nextStep];
    int nextSumNeg = sumSoFar - nums[nextStep];
    int nextRest = rest - nums[nextStep];

    boolean pos = false;
    if ((nextSumPos > target && nextSumPos - nextRest > target) ||  
        (nextSumPos < target && nextSumPos + nextRest < target)) { /* do nothing */  }
    else { pos = true; }

    boolean neg = false;
    if ((nextSumNeg > target && nextSumNeg - nextRest > target) ||
        (nextSumNeg < target && nextSumNeg + nextRest < target)) { /* do nothing */ }
    else { neg = true; }

    if (pos && neg) {
        return helper(nextStep, nextSumPos, nums, target, nextRest)
            +  helper(nextStep, nextSumNeg, nums, target, nextRest);
    }else if (pos && !neg) {
        return helper(nextStep, nextSumPos, nums, target, nextRest);
    } else if (!pos && neg) {
        return helper(nextStep, nextSumNeg, nums, target, nextRest);
    } else { /* !pos && !neg */
        return 0;
    }

}

private static int arraySum(int[] nums) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        sum += nums[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```